# Order by total COUNT relative to repeating columns MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count

Firstly, apologies for the terrible title, I couldn't think of any other way to explain it.

I have a table that looks something like this :

```
ID  plays  track_id
1   23     1
2   8      2
3   100    1
4   4      2
5   10     3
```

I want to return the results so all **plays** for the same **track_id** are added together and then ordered by the **track_id** with the most plays first.
So, in table form, the results from the above would look like this :

```
plays   track_id
123     1
12      2
10      3
```

But I'm totally lost on how to formulate this MySQL query in php.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(plays) as plays, track_id
FROM Tracks
GROUP BY track_id
ORDER BY SUM(plays) DESC
```

Comment: I've been dabbling with this stuff for about 15 years now and this is the first time I've ever had to use SUM. Haha! Thank you so much, I would have never worked this out as I didn't know what I was looking for.